# SQL accommodating meter rollover in utility meter readings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The job is actually a machine cycle count that rolls over to zero at 32,000 but the utility / electricity / odometer analogy gets the idea across.

Let's say we have a three digit meter. After 999 it will roll over to 0.

```
Reading  Value      Difference
      1    990               -
      2    992               2
      3    997               5
      4    003               6 *
      5    008               5
```

I have a CTE query generating the difference between rows but the line

```
    Cur.Value - Prv.Value as Difference
```

on reading 4 above returns -994 due to the clock rollover. (It should return '6'.)

Can anyone suggest an SQL trick to accommodate the rollover?

e.g., Here's a trick to get around SQL's lack of "GREATEST" function.

```
-- SQL doesn't have LEAST/GREATEST functions so we use a math trick 
-- to return the  greater number:
-- 0.5*((A+B) + abs(A-B))
0.5 * (Cur._VALUE - Prv._VALUE + ABS(Cur._VALUE - Prv._VALUE)) AS Difference
```

Can anyone suggest a similar trick for the rollover problem?

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce9d4/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CASE`statement to detect the negative value-- which indicates a rollover condition-- and compensate for it:

```
--Create CTE
;WITH tblDifference AS
(
    SELECT Row_Number() 
    OVER (ORDER BY Reading) AS RowNumber, Reading, Value
    FROM t1
)
SELECT 
    Cur.Reading AS This, 
    Cur.Value AS ThisRead,
    Prv.Value AS PrevRead,
    CASE WHEN Cur.Value - Prv.Value < 0 -- this happens during a rollover
        THEN Cur.Value - Prv.Value + 1000 -- compensate for the rollover
        ELSE Cur.Value - Prv.Value
    END as Difference 
FROM
tblDifference Cur 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblDifference Prv
ON Cur.RowNumber=Prv.RowNumber+1
ORDER BY Cur.Reading
```